# VBA: User defined type as event parameter in public object module

Tags: vba, user-defined-types

In my excel workbook, I want to implement an event sender <> receiver concept (OOP).

That works generally, but I cannot pass user defined types (UDT) as event parameters from one public sheet class to another.

The UDT (tCompliance) was defined in a standard module as public:

```
Option Explicit

Public Type tCompliance
  deliverable As String
  businessObject As String
  process As String
  instruction As String
  classification As String
End Type
```

The sender sheet "tblCompliance" has the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Event tableChanged(compliance As tCompliance)

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim lr As ListRow, compliance As tCompliance
  
  If Not Intersect(Target, table.DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then
    Set lr = getListRow(table, Target)
    With compliance
      .deliverable = lr.Range(1, 1).value
      .process = lr.Range(1, 2).value
      .instruction = lr.Range(1, 3).value
      .classification = lr.Range(1, 4).value
    End With
    RaiseEvent tableChanged(compliance)
  End If
End Sub
```

The receiver sheet "tblPlanning" has the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents me_tblCompliance As tblCompliance

Private Sub me_tblCompliance_tableChanged(compliance As tCompliance)
  // Stuff here
end Sub
```

The error messages that I get do not make much sense in combination.

The first error says **"Only user defined types that are defined IN PUBLIC OBJECT MODULES ... can be passed to a runtime function."**

So apparently the solution is to put the UDT definition into an PUBLIC OBJECT MODULE.
I put it into the PUBLIC OBJECT MODULE "thisWorkbook" and tried again to compile the code.

But then I get the second error message: **A public defined type can not be defined in an OBJECT MODULE**

So I tried to put the UDT into a class module which I made "2 - PublicNotCreatable" in the VBE properties section.

But then I get the same error message: **A public user defined type can not be defined in an OBJECT MODULE"**

VBA seems to be very inconsistent here.

Comment: UDTs are a bit of a red herring in VBA. OKish for intra module/class use but problematical otherwise. The quick and dirty replacement is a variant( containing an array) and a public enum which matches your UDT fields, or a proper job where you convert your UDT to an Class.

Comment: I had this idea also, and switched to this solution. It seems to work. At least the mentioned error messages are gone. The class module must be "2 - PublicNotCreatable" for this to work.

Comment: It can work in a sheet module too, but with some small adaptations...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to work in a sheet module, the above code should be adapted as following

1. The receiver sheet code should be adapted in the next way:

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents me_tblCompliance As tblCompliance 'tblCompliance  should be the sheet code module class

Public Sub me_tblCompliance_tableChanged(compliance As tCompliance) 'Mandatory to be Public
  ''' Stuff here
   MsgBox compliance.deliverable & " - " & compliance.instruction
End Sub
```

2. The line raising the event should be transformed from

```
RaiseEvent tableChanged(compliance)
```

in

```
RaiseEvent tblPlanning.me_tblCompliance_tableChanged(compliance)
```

The code must call the event not like in a standard module, but fully qualified using the sheet code module class(`tblPlanning`):

Then, the event itself should be called (`me_tblCompliance_tableChanged`)

Please, test this way and send some feedback.

Anyhow, interesting question... :)

Comment: @ FaneDuru: I will test it and give you feedback. What I can say is that the names "tblCompliance" and "tblPlanning" already are the code names of the worksheet "classes".

Comment: @user14181536: If so, it should be good to use it as `tblCompliance`. When used between double quotes it is (here) understood as the sheet name... I will adapt the code in this way, mentioned what `tblCompliance` is, or it should be. But I tested the solution and it works without any problem. Of course with two existing sheets on my testing workbook...

Comment: @ FaneDuru: I tested the changed code according to your suggestions and it works. Thank you. Key was the fully qualified name in the line `RaiseEvent tblPlanning.me_tblCompliance_tableChanged(compliance)`. The only thing I could mention is that in the described solution the sender code module must know the handler function name of the receiving code module.  Does this match OOP principles? What if I had several receiving code modules? Maybe my thoughts are wrong here...

Comment: @user14181536: I am afraid that this is the single possibility... Even a simple procedure cannot be called from a sheet module without fully qualifying it, like in a standard module. It looks that all objects able to raise events behave in this way. Theoretically, only a class may wrap the event and then allocate it to the objects you need. I know how to do it for standard/defined events in case of controls created on the fly, but I never even tried it for a custom event. I am busy for a while, but I will maybe give it a try in the next future...

Comment: @ FaneDuru: Thanks for your help. The solution provided is a valid answer to the issue in my point of view.